# Cannot Assign to Value: Function call returns immutable value

Tags: swift, tableview

Trying to place labels on a table but getting an error which I haven't seen before. Other cannot assign to property error questions don't seem to match what I'm my situation so posting the question here. Any pointers would really be appreciated as I'm learning by Stack Overflow. Thanks!

```
import UIKit

class SeventhViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 15   

}

internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    var newData = [String]()

    newData = ["Impressions","Image Tapped","Description Tapped","Biography Tapped","Purchase Link Tapped","Added to Collection","Removed from Collection"]

    //Programmatically create label
    var impressionsLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 280.0, y: 14.0, width: 300.0, height: 30.0))
    impressionsLabel.text = newData[indexPath.row]
    impressionsLabel.tag = 1
    impressionsLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Impressions", size: 17.0)

    impressionsLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray

    cell.addSubview(impressionsLabel)
    **cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) = newData[indexPath.row]**
    impressionsLabel.tag = 1

    return cell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is with the line:

```
cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) = newData[indexPath.row]
```

Two problems. `viewWithTag` returns an optional `UIView`. You then attempt to assign a `String` to the `UIView`.

Assuming the view with tag `1` is a `UILabel`, you need something like this:

```
if let label = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel {
    label.text = newData[indexPath.row]
}
```

This safely deals with accessing a possibly nil view (incase there is no actual view with a tag of `1`) and attempting to cast that view to a `UILabel` (incase the view isn't actually a `UILabel`). If those conditions are met and you actually get a label, then you set the label's `text` property.

Unrelated to your issue (it will cause a new issue when you run your app), but it makes no sense to have your data array declared and setup in the `cellForRowAt` method and it makes no sense to hardcode a specific count in your `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

The proper thing to do would be to make `newData` a property of your view controller and set it up once instead of every time a cell is accessed. And then return its count in `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. It cleared my immediate error which is great. Now I just have to look into making 'newData' a property.